# Traverse JSON tree and in Ruby and format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, tree

my request returns any type of JSON. I would like to give a key to each attribute recursively in Ruby.

```
{
  "name": "My name",
  "age": 17,
  "users": [
    {
      "name": "John Doe",
      "colours": [
        "blue",
        "red"
      ],
      "animals": [
        {
          "name": "Panthera"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

It should traverse the tree and return:

```
[ 'name', 'age', 'users[]' 'users[]name', 'users[]colours', 'users[]animals', users[]animals[]name' ]
```

I can get top-level keys by calling `Hash.keys` but not sure how to traverse the tree and return custom key. Thanks for your help.

```
j = {"name":"My name","age":17,"users":[{"name":"John Doe","colours":["blue","red"],"animals":[{"name":"Panthera"}]}]}
a = []
j.keys.each do |key|
  if key.class == Array
    a << "#{key}[]"
  else
    a << key
  end
end
a
```

Comment: Please read "[mcve]" and "[ask]". We don't know what you've tried so any answers could duplicate your search, wasting our time and yours. Instead, show us the minimum code you wrote that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to achieve what you want. You were on the right track thinking recursively. I added comments to explain what's happening.

```
require 'json'

# Convert JSON to a ruby hash
j = JSON.parse('{"name":"My name","age":17,"users":[{"name":"John Doe","colours":["blue","red"],"animals":[{"name":"Panthera"}]}]}')
a = []

def make_array_from_hash_keys(array, hash, prefix = "")
  # Iterate through the hash's key/value pairs
  hash.each do |key, value|
    # If the value is an array, we set a new prefix and add that to the main
    # array. Then we iterate through this inner array to see if there are more
    # hashes. If there are, call the parent method to generate more elements
    # for the array, using the new prefix.
    if value.class == Array
      new_prefix = "#{prefix + key}[]"
      array << new_prefix

      hash[key].each do |array_value|
        if array_value.class == Hash
          # |= makes sure that the final array elements are unique
          array |= make_array_from_hash_keys(array, array_value, new_prefix)
        end
      end

    # If the value is not an array, simply add it to the main array with the
    # necessary prefix
    else
      array << prefix + key
    end
  end

  array
end

new_array = make_array_from_hash_keys(a, j)
puts new_array.inspect
# Gives us:
# ["name", "age", "users[]", "users[]name", "users[]colours[]", "users[]animals[]", "users[]animals[]name"]
```

Comment: Thank you very much and the comments, although it is self-explanatory. Much appreciated.